# `binary:logitraw` vs `binary:logistic` objective in xgboost

Tags: python, machine-learning, logistic-regression, xgboost, xgbclassifier

Which are the differences between setting `objective='binary:logistic'` and `objective='binary:logitraw'` in a xgboost classifier?

Based on the documentation (https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/parameter.html#learning-task-parameters), the former corresponds to `logistic regression for binary classification, output probability`, while the latter is `logistic regression for binary classification, output score before logistic transformation`.

It is not clear to me what these mean in practice. Could you explain which functions are minimized during training for the two cases?

Also it appears that setting the `objective` parameter does not change the model output at all, as in the code below.

Simulate data:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import xgboost as xgb

x1 = np.random.uniform(low=-3,high=4,size=10000) 
x2 = np.random.uniform(low=-3,high=4,size=10000)
x3 = np.random.uniform(low=-3,high=4,size=10000)
X = pd.DataFrame({'x1':x1, 'x2':x2, 'x3':x3})
z =  2 * x1 + 3 * x2 + 4 * x3

def invlogit(z):
    p = 1 / (1 + np.exp(- z)) 
    return p

pr = invlogit(z)
y = pd.Series(data=np.random.binomial(size=10000, n=1, p=pr))
```

Define two classifiers, all parameters are the same except `objective`:

```
 params={'gamma': 1.4,
 'learning_rate': 0.2,
 'max_delta_step': 5.,
 'max_depth': 8,
 'min_child_weight': 2.2,
 'subsample': 0.7,
 'objective':'binary:logistic',
 'nthread':4,
 'seed':2,
 'num_boost_round':200,
 'reg_alpha':0,
 'reg_lambda':0
}
clf = xgb.XGBClassifier(**params)
clf.fit(X, y)
tmp1=params.copy()
tmp1['objective']='binary:logitraw'
clf1=xgb.XGBClassifier(**tmp1)
clf1.fit(X, y)
```

Plot predictions (`invlogit` is the inverse of a logit function and gives a probability).

```
plt.plot(invlogit(clf.predict(X, output_margin=True)),
         invlogit(clf1.predict(X, output_margin=True)),'.')
plt.xlabel('binary:logistic');
plt.ylabel('binary:logitraw');
```

[image]

I'm confused, the results are the same for both cases. Any guess? Thanks!